# How can grunt replace HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to copy markup from dust templates to JSP. I have many JSP pages where I want to replace the spans with localize classes with a spring tag

```
    <div class="push-right">
      <a href="/credentials/login">
      <span class="localize" name="top_bar.sign_in">Sign In</span>
      </a> |
      <a href="/credentials/register">
      <span class="localize" name="top_bar.register">Register</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

So this block should become like this.

```
    <div class="push-right">
      <a href="/credentials/login">
        <spring:message code="top_bar.sign_in" />
      </a> |
      <a href="/credentials/register">
        <spring:message code="top_bar.register" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**
@Sam provided a good RegEx example that I am now following. I am constructing an object that I push to an array

```
var reLocalize = new RegExp('<span(?=[^>]*?class="localize").*?name="([^"]*).*?<\/span>', 'g');
localizeReplaceObject.match = reLocalize;
localizeReplaceObject.replacement = '<spring:message code=$1 />';
localizeReplaceArray.push(localizeReplaceObject);
```

then I run grunt replace

```
    replace: {
      localize: {
        options: {
          patterns: localizeReplaceArray
        }
        ,files: [
        {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp'], dest: '../WEB-INF/views/'}
        ]
    }
```

I run grunt again `grunt replace:localize` but the index.jsp localize tags don't update.

```
Running "replace:localize" (replace) task
Verifying property replace.localize exists in config...OK
Files: ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp -> ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
Options: encoding="utf8", mode=false, processContentExclude=[], patterns=[{"match":{},"replacement":"<spring:message code=$1 />"}], excludeBuiltins=false, force
filePair src ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
Reading ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp...OK
Processing source...Replace ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp → ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
OK
Writing ../WEB-INF/views/index.jsp...OK

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: i dont know how to do it but you can achieve this - quickest fix will be from command prompt, select folder and file and run to rename, you will get enough tutorials in google

Comment: jQuery works on DOM/XML nodes, not HTML source. Unless there's something in the Grunt environment that I don't yet know about, what you are asking for appears to be impossible.

Comment: I'm referring to jquery `$.each` as an analogy. Is there a way to achieve this looping ability within grunt to replace the content by piping in the attribute name?

Comment: It would be less confusing if the text made it clear that the code block is pseudo-code.

Comment: I think you will find that Python is the generally preferred tool for source manipulations of this kind.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-replace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099324/replace-a-block-of-html-with-another-block-of-html-using-grunt/30101007#30101007

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-replace) (thanks, @Pinal) with the following expression to match `span` elements with `class="localize"` and capture the `name` attribute:

```
<span(?=[^>]*?class="localize").*?name="([^"]*).*?<\/span>
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/cU5sE6/1)

Comment: I'm having some issues though with the grunt-replace. I had an example that I used to construct a regex for image name replacement where I create an object in an array but that expression does not seem to work still. I'll post a code update