# Replace a block of html with another block of html using grunt

Tags: html, gruntjs

I have a block of html something like this -

```
<div class = "logo">
 <a href = "homepage.html"><img src = "logo.png"></a>
 <nav><a href = "#"> Sign In </a></nav>
</div>
```

I am automating my html template using grunt. All I want is, when I run grunt task it replace

```
<a href = "homepage.html"><img src = "logo.png"></a>
```

with `{{logo}}`
so that the final html will become

```
<div class = "logo">
 {{logo}}
 <nav><a href = "#"> Sign In </a></nav>
</div>
```

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thankx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace), you can do something like this:

```
'string-replace': {
    logo: {
        files: [{
            src: 'path/to/file.html',
            dest: 'path/to/file.html'
        }],
        options: {
            replacements: [{
                pattern: '<img src = "logo.png">',
                replacement: '{{logo}}'
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to loadNpmTask and run it like:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');
grunt.registerTask('replace', ['string-replace:logo']);
```

Reminder, according to the 'grunt-string-replace' docs:

> Replaces strings on files by using string or regex patterns
>   (...)
>   grunt-string-replace is basically a wrapper of String.prototype.replace you can also provide a function as a replacement pattern instead of a string or a template.

Comment: Thank u so much @jmartins. it works but not showing replaced html in my dest (dest: 'dist/header.html') file.  :-) I mean to say that in my final dest file its not showing me {{logo}} in html.

Comment: that's strange. I used the same path here to test and it's working fine and showing {{logo}} in the dist file. Are you sure you're matching exactly the tag `<img src = "logo.png">`??

Comment: I'm trying to do this - 'string-replace': {
      logo: {
        files: [{
            src: 'build/views/header.html',
            dest: 'dist/header.html'
        }],
        options: {
          replacements: [{
              pattern: '<a href="/home-page.html" title="Home"><img alt="Logo" src="../images/logo.png"></a>',
              replacement: '{{logo}}'
          }]
        }
      }
    }

Comment: and could you give a sample of your html?

Comment: Not necessary. I tested here and worked fine. I'm just wondering if you are matching this `<a href="/home-page.html" title="Home"><img alt="Logo" src="../images/logo.png"></a>`exactly as it is in the gruntfile in your 'build/views/header.html'. Are you skipping lines between tags(E.g.: <a> and <img>)?

Comment: To see it working just change in your string-replace config the pattern to this only `<img alt="Logo" src="../images/logo.png">`.

Comment: I'm not doing anything different from you. If you just add this exact line `<a href="/home-page.html" title="Home"><img alt="Logo" src="../images/logo.png"></a>` WITHOUT LINE BREAKS or extra spaces to your file "build/views/header.html" you gonna see the magic happening.

Comment: Tho, if you could paste here just the SAMPLE of lines in your file "build/views/header.html" which has the tags you want to replace would be great to spot the problem.

Comment: The `pattern` in the 'grunt-string-replace' uses regex. Either you give a exactly pattern (like you're doing), or you give this pattern in a regex form if you want to have line breaks, or sth like that, between the tags you want to match with that pattern.

Comment: <div class="logo" id="logo">
      <a href="/home-page.html" title="Home">
        <img alt="Logo" src="../images/logo.png">
      </a>
      <nav class="user-nav sign-in visible-xs">
        <a class="login" data-sso-action="signin" href="#" role="button">Sign In</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cogunadivu/1/edit?html - my build/views/header.html looks like this

Comment: Ok. So the sample you sent is formatted like this - http://jsfiddle.net/t6a0gys5/, right?

Comment: So, now change it to this http://jsfiddle.net/t6a0gys5/2/ and run the `grunt replace`

Comment: Thank u for your patience and your answers @jmartins. There might be some other problem because of which its not workking properly. Should I uninstall it and then install it again?

Comment: So, just to be clear, I don't if you understood. But if the 'grunt-string-replace' task is running and creating a new file without the replacements the only possible problem is your string is not matching the expected in the pattern.

Comment: Does not need to install it again. Just need to match the pattern in the string replace. Try replacing sth else, and you will see it working.

Comment: Also, an upvote or marking my answer as the correct one would be very nice :)

Comment: @TanviSingh also look into grunt-string-replace [documentation](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace)

Comment: Finally that magic happens. You was right @jmartins. Thankx :-)

Comment: @TanviSingh Great! o/